# clang-800.0.42.1 and open mp

Tags: c++, clang, openmp

I'm running max os x 10.11.6 and want to include openmp in my programs, meaning compile with -fopenmp which is giving me the error:

clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

clan --version is giving me:

Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

According to 
https://clang-omp.github.io/

clang supports openmp from version 3.7 onwards.

My first question is how does "clang-800.0.42.1" relate to "clang 3.7", so do I actually have open mp support?

My second question is, according to this simple example: 
http://blog.llvm.org/2015/05/openmp-support_22.html
I have to tell clang where the omp header files and libs are located as well as add the libs to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. But what are the files and libs exactly called and where can I find them? I'm running default xcode without any homebrew/special compiler stuff installed.

Thx for the help!